# Is "Salaamun Alekum" in a question "religious content"?

Tags: discussion, review, edits, suggested-edits

A suggested edit came up in the queue that I wasn't sure how to handle:

[image]
*(The link to the edit suggestion may or may not work for other users)*

Although it is true it is unnecessary for the question, should it be removed? I guess the real question is, is *Salaamun Alekum* considered to be "religious content" on StackExchange, or is it more akin to a new user writing (which happens rather frequently):

> Good morning. My C# `ExecuteSqlCommand` is not returning output from stored procedure.

Comment: All greetings, salutation and other noise should be removed, religious or not.

Comment: for reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: I do recall asking something similar to this a couple years back somewhere else on the site: [_Travel StackExchange: Does the traditional Arabic greeting (As-salamu alaykum) have religous meaning?_](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/26132/13025)

Comment: @rene Ah, excellent, I wasn't sure if editing out greetings would be considered too minor. Do you want to add that comment as an answer?

Comment: I would personally stay away from calling the stuff I remove *religious content* even if the editor knows were she/he is talking about. Don't want to start a war over a misunderstanding...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think it translates as:

> Peace be upon you

and as such qualifies as a greeting that should be removed:

> [Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)

I could not imagine a Wikipedia page starting with "Good Morning", "Peace be upon you" or "Salaamun Alekum", and our Q&As are wikis too.